# Creating an array of generic (but typed on declaration) expressions

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
public static Expression<Func<object, object>>[] Expressions() 
    => new Expression<Func<object, object>>[]
        {
            (Type1 t1) => t1.t1Field,
            (Type2 t2) => t2.t2Field,
            ...
            (TypeN tN) => tN.tNField
        };
```

The compiler does not like the `Type[i]` part: `Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'Expression<Func<object, object>>' because the parameter types do not match the delegate parameter`.

I have tried using `dynamic` instead of `object`, but it didn't work.

I have also tried to achieve something like this, without success:

```
public static Expression<Func<object, object>> Cast<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
```

Comment: Can´t you just uise a list of `Delegate`? Relying on the statically typed `Func<T, T1, ...>` assumes you know those types at compile-time. What you seem to want is providing the corect types at *runtime*. Apart from this even **if** you could store different expressions into a single list, how would you compile them and call the appropriate delegate? They´re just of type `Func<object, object>` which would allow to pass an instance of `Type2` to the first element as well.

Comment: @HimBromBeere The final goal is to later extract the property name as a string, via `memberExpr.ToString()`. I am not experienced enough to know if this could work with delegates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return type is an array of lambdas that accept object and return object. But you return an array of lambdas each of them accept some user type. So simplest way to make it work is to add type cast:

```
public static Expression<Func<object, object>>[] Expressions()
  => new Expression<Func<object, object>>[]
  {
      (Object o) => ((Type1)o).t1Field,
      (Object o) => ((Type2)o).t2Field,
  };
```

Comment: This is perfect, I didn't think of this solution! Thanks. It can be even simplified to `(o) => ((Type1)o).t1Field`, the first `object` is inferred from the array declaration.

Comment: This approach is dangerous if you call one of those delegates, e.g. `expressions[0].Compile()(instanceOfType2);` which will cause an `InvalidCastException`. So you don´t get any typ-safety by using a`Func<object, object>`.  That´s why I added my comment above.